# Using Own Stack Class in Encoding Program - Determine Size and Top

Tags: c++, class, stack, lvalue, member-functions

I wrote a encoding program using the C++ stack library.  Now I am trying to implement my own stack class, however I notice there are size() and top() member functions in the stack library.  I am not sure how to implement my code without these functions, or how to write those functions in my class to get them to work properly with the code I already have.

Here is the areas that the stack library functions are being called in my `readFileEncode(string filename, stack<char> &text, string cypher)` function:

```
ifstream file(fileName, ios::in | ios::binary);
stack<char> temp;
char ch;

while (file.get(ch)){
    temp.push(ch ^ cypher[temp.size() % cypher.length()]);
}

while (!temp.isEmpty()){
    text.push(temp.top());
    temp.pop();
}
```

Here is my stack class:

```
#include<iostream>

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

template <class TYPE>

class stack{
struct node{
    TYPE element;
    node *next;
};

public:
node *top;
int stackSize;

stack(void);            //constructor
~stack(void);           //destructor free the stack

void push(TYPE & value);
TYPE pop(void);
TYPE peek(void);
int isEmpty(void);      //returns TRUE if empty
void print(void);
void reset(void);       //pop all the elements off the stack
size_t size(void) const;
TYPE topOf(void) const;
};

template <class TYPE>
stack<TYPE>::stack(void){
top = NULL;
stackSize = 0;
}

template <class TYPE>
stack<TYPE>::~stack(void){
cout << "Entering Stack Destructor" << endl;
reset();
cout << "Exiting Stack Destructor" << endl;
}

template <class TYPE>
void stack<TYPE>::push(TYPE & value){
node *temp = new node;

if (temp == NULL){
    cout << "Push: Memory Allocation Error" << endl;
    exit(1);
}

temp->element = value;
temp->next = top;
top = temp;
stackSize++;
}

template <class TYPE>
TYPE stack<TYPE>::pop(void){
TYPE returnElement;

if (top != NULL){
    node *temp = top;
    returnElement = top->element;
    top = top->next;
    delete temp;        //delete the node
    stackSize--;
}

return(returnElement);
}

template <class TYPE>
TYPE stack<TYPE>::peek(void){
TYPE returnElement;
if (top != NULL)
    returnElement = top->element;
cout << "Peek: " << returnElement << endl;
return(returnElement);
}

template <class TYPE>
int stack<TYPE>::isEmpty(void){
if (stackSize == 0)
    return(TRUE);
else
    return(FALSE);
}

template <class TYPE>
void stack<TYPE>::reset(void){
cout << "Reset Stack" << endl;
while (isEmpty() != TRUE){
    pop();
}
}

template <class TYPE>
void stack<TYPE>::print(void){
cout << "Inside Print Stack" << endl;
cout << "Stack size = " << stackSize << endl;

node * temp = top;
while (temp != NULL){
    cout << " " << temp->element << endl;
    temp = temp->next;
}
}

template <class TYPE>
size_t size(void) const{
return stackSize;
}

template <class TYPE>
TYPE stack<TYPE>::topOf(void) const{
return (*top).element;
}
```

This stack class is based on what I know of stack's.  If there is anything wrong, it is because this is the first time I have written a stack class.

So basically, I am having problems either 1) writing the `size()` and `top()` functions, or 2) rewriting the while loops in my `readFileEncode()` function to use what I have.  I had help properly writing the code to work with the stack library, but now trying to implement my own class is causing me problems. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT 1: With the help of dyp, I changed the variable name of `int size` to `int stackSize` everywhere it appears in the class.  Also, I change the function `top()` to `topOf()`

EDIT 2: Changed `void push(TYPE &value)` to `void push(TYPE const& value)` in all instances. Code is updated above. I used the following `main()` to test the class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "stack.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
stack<int> s;
s.push(1);
s.push(2);
s.push(3);
s.push(4);
s.push(5);

cout << "size: " << s.size() << endl;
cout << "top element: " << s.topOf() << endl;

s.pop();
s.pop();

cout << "size: " << s.size() << endl;
cout << "top element: " << s.topOf() << endl;
cout << "empty: " << s.isEmpty() << endl;

s.pop();
s.pop();
s.pop();

cout << "size: " << s.size() << endl;
//cout << "top element: " << s.top() << endl;
cout << "empty: " << s.isEmpty() << endl;

system ("pause");
}
```

Everything worked fine, however when I attached the stack.h file to my encoding program, I get the following errors:

At `file.put(text.top());` I get "term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments," and the same error at `text.push(temp.top());`. I get the error, but not exactly sure how to fix it.

I also had to move `public:` in my class above `node *top; int stackSize;` because I got errors about them being private. This was not a problem with my test program. Not sure if that is ok either.

Comment: There are some issues with your code, so I recommend you post it on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) for review once it's working. Note that the Standard Library's `stack` returns nothing (`void`) on `pop`, and returns a *reference* for `top`. Can you show us what you have tried / what are the problems with implementing `size()` and `top()`?

Comment: @dyp Hey, I didn't even know there was a separate CodeReview area of the StackExchange. Thanks. I will post there when it is finished. Actually, I have only gotten my stack class to work with simple stack operations in main. I have tried writing my own size and top member functions, which I have updated above, but I get some declaration errors and definition errors, so I obviously am going about it all wrong.  I am still pretty new to writing classes, and struggling to get all member functions declared properly.

Comment: Note that you can't have two members of the same name (other than overloaded functions). Rename either the data member `int size;` or the member function `size_t size() const;`.

Comment: Ok, I did that. Same with top then? I changed the function `top()` to `topOf()`. When I try to test this class with `stack<int> s; s.push(1)` I get a error stating that "initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue." What is causing this?

Comment: What is wrong with using what the language provides (stack template, in this case)?

Comment: @vonbrand What do you mean? Why am I not sticking with the stack library in C++? If that is what you are asking, it is because I am required to build my own stack class. I am not sure if that is what you are asking.

Comment: @CharlWillia6, OK, that is a reasonable explanation.

Comment: @CharlWillia6 Well your program isn't "const-correct" (one of the issues I wanted to point out in a code review answer). This problem is caused by your `push` function taking a non-const lvalue reference, but you pass a prvalue (a value): `1` is a value, which cannot be changed, hence you cannot bind it to a non-const reference. You can fix that by using `void push(TYPE const&);`

Comment: @dyp Ok, I see that. I took the ampersand out and everything worked. I went back and put `const&` back in like you have suggested and everything works. I am still such a newbie, I don't really totally understand the difference as to why it worked without `&` and then with `const&`.  I am posting my answer here in a minute.

Comment: I updated my post above. Almost there, but still getting some errors. Also had some problems with private and public declarations.

Comment: You renamed the function `top()` to `topOf()`, so you should use that new name ;) `text.top` refers to the private data member, which is not a function taking zero arguments (but just an `int`). -> `text.topOf()` should do.

Comment: @dyp Actually I did just notice that on my own. Haha. Yeah, I know, flew right past me there. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following code to test my stack:

```
 int main()
{
stack<int> s;
s.push(1);
s.push(2);
s.push(3);
s.push(4);
s.push(5);

cout << "size: " << s.size() << endl;
cout << "top element: " << s.topOf() << endl;

s.pop();
s.pop();

cout << "size: " << s.size() << endl;
cout << "top element: " << s.topOf() << endl;
cout << "empty: " << s.isEmpty() << endl;

s.pop();
s.pop();
s.pop();

cout << "size: " << s.size() << endl;
//cout << "top element: " << s.top() << endl;
cout << "empty: " << s.isEmpty() << endl;

system ("pause");
}
```

I changed the code in my following stack class to the following and it seems to have worked:

```
void push(TYPE const& value);
size_t size(void) const;
TYPE topOf(void) const;
```

and:

```
void stack<TYPE>::push(TYPE const& value){
node *temp = new node;

if (temp == NULL){
    cout << "Push: Memory Allocation Error" << endl;
    exit(1);
}

temp->element = value;
temp->next = top;
top = temp;
stackSize++;
}

template <class TYPE>
size_t stack<TYPE>::size(void) const{
return stackSize;
}

template <class TYPE>
TYPE stack<TYPE>::topOf(void) const{
return (*top).element;
}
```

Also changed all occurrences of `top()` in my main to `topOf()`. Not sure if this is all proper, but it works, and I will take dyp's advice and turn it in at [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).